# Simplest way to integrate this expression : $\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} e^{-x^2/2} dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, statistics, normal-distribution

I'm toying around with statistics and calculus for a project of mine and I'm trying to find the simplest/fastest way to integrate this formula :

$$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} e^{-x^2/2} dx$$

- I do not want to use a table.
- I'm taking this opportunity to get more practice with my new calculus skills
- It seems that a Taylor series approx is the only way to go

Best Regards

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_integral

Comment: Good question but surely a duplicate.

Comment: Taylor series might be involved if it were an indefinite integral or had finite bounds other than $0$, but for the integral over the whole line, one can prove that it's $\sqrt{2\pi\  {}}$ by any of several methods not involving Taylor series. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: Try googling "Gaussian Integral Trick"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If we set $$I := \int_{\mathbb{R}} \exp \left(- \frac{x^2}{2} \right) \, dx,$$ 
then

$$I^2 = \int_{\mathbb{R}} \int_{\mathbb{R}} \exp \left( - \frac{x^2+y^2}{2} \right) \, dx \, dy.$$

Introducting polar coordinates, i.e.

$$\begin{pmatrix} x \\ y \end{pmatrix}  = \begin{pmatrix} r \cos \varphi \\ r \sin \varphi \end{pmatrix},$$

yields

$$I^2 = \int_{r=0}^{\infty} \int_{\varphi=0}^{2\pi} e^{-r^2/2} r \, dr \, d\varphi = \left( \int_{0}^{\infty} r e^{-r^2/2} \, dr \right) \left( \int_{\varphi=0}^{2\pi} d \varphi \right).$$

This expression can be easily calculated.

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 2):

The "easiest" way is to use a change of variables to change your integral into a multiple of

$$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}e^{-u^2}\,du$$

and use the [famous fact](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_integral) that that last integral equals $\sqrt{\pi}$.

Comment: The value of $\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-x^2/2}\; dx$ is just as famous.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Change variables into the integral $\displaystyle\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} e^{-x^2}\,dx$, square that, then transform into a polar integration.