# How does k in $\int_{-\infty}^\infty ke^{\frac{-x^2}{2}} ~dx =1$ solve to $k = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}$

Tags: calculus, statistics

I'm working on stats problems and am a bit rusty with calculus as I haven't worked with it in 3 years. My prof gave us an equation
$\int_{-\infty}^\infty ke^{\frac{-x^2}{2}} ~dx =1$ where XER and f(x) is a PDF to solve for k.

Could someone please explain to me how he arrived at $k = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}$

Comment: This comes from the beautiful gaussian result: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/9286/proving-int-0-infty-mathrme-x2-dx-dfrac-sqrt-pi2

Comment: $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} k \exp(-\frac{x^2}{2}) \, dx = k \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \exp(-\frac{x^2}{2}) \, dx$, so if you believe the latter integral evaluates to $\sqrt{2\pi}$, you're done. There are a lot of good proofs for this.

Comment: Substitute $\frac{x^2}{2}=t$ and go from there.

Comment: @G.Sassatelli I think the integrand becomes $e^{-t}\frac{1}{\sqrt {2t}}$ actually.

Comment: @StubbornAtom Yes: it wouldn't have changed my point, though. However, I found a method of solution in the linked question which used it, and I therefore decided to put on some duct tape. :D

Comment: It's basically http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1343672/321264